# Wordpress custom template redirecting with two variables

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I have rewrite rule like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule( '([^/]+)/([^/]+)/var1/var2', 'index.php?category_name=$matches[1]/$matches[2]&var1=yes&var2=yes', 'top' );
```

Now i don't know how to redirect custom page template to this url, i've tried sth like this, but it doesn;t work:

```
    if ( get_query_var( 'var1' ) && get_query_var( 'var2' )) {
    add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
        return get_template_directory() . '/var1-var2.php';
    });
}
```

Maybe I know what's the problem but i can't solve it, for one var i have code like this:

```
if ( get_query_var( 'var1' )) {
    add_filter( 'template_include', function() {
        return get_template_directory() . '/var1.php';
    });
}
```

Should i Do this like that?

```
if ( get_query_var( 'var1' ) && get_query_var( 'var2' ) is empty)
```

Anybody know hot to fix it?

Comment: Anybody knows how to do it? With one variable it works fine, but when i add second variable it doesn't redirect to the template

Comment: When you `echo get_query_var( 'var2' );`, does it display any output? Have you added both `var1` and `var2` to the public query variables?